# Regex to match from first uppercase to end of sentence of string to highlight array of words

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match-all

I know the title is quite complicate to understand. 
Basically i got a text lets say around 20000 chars.

When i perform a search i want to extract the sentence where any of the matched words are found and highlight them.

I got an array of the words to highlight called $words , and let call the main text $text.
So my code is the following:

```
foreach($words as $word):

    $regex = '/[^.!?\n]*\b'.preg_quote($word,"/").'\b[^.!?\n]*/i';

    preg_match_all($regex, $text, $matches);  
    count($matches[0]) > 3 ? $search_q= 3 : $search_q=count($matches[0]);

    for ($i=0; $i < $search_q; $i++):
        echo preg_replace('/\b('.preg_quote($word,"/").')\b/i','<span class="highlighted">$1</span>',$matches[0][$i]).'[..]  ';
    endfor;
endforeach;
```

Problem with this code is when 2 words belongs to the same sentence , then the sentence will be printed twice. I want to print it just once with both words highlighted but i dont got a clue on how to do that.

Thanks for the help guys

UPDATE: TEST SCENARIO

Lets supose that:

```
$text="A new holiday shopping tradition: Smartphones and social networks

Many consumers will take out their phones before their wallets this holiday season with even more visiting social media sites before tackling their gift lists.

More than one-quarter (27 percent) of smartphone owners plan to use their devices for holiday shopping to search for store locations (67 percent), compare prices (59 percent) and check product availability (46 percent).  Additionally, 44 percent say they plan to use social media to seek discounts, read reviews and check family and friends’ gift lists.

“Consumers are using online and mobile platforms to make the most of their holiday budgets, and the survey indicates that they will do more than just compare prices,” said Paul.  “Retailers that use mobile and online channels to show product availability, locations and pricing but add customized promotions and gift ideas may encourage shoppers to come in the door for a specific gift and take additional items to the register.”";
```

And the words are:

```
$words=array('social','media');
```

With my code i get this:

```
A new holiday shopping tradition: Smartphones and **social** networks[..]
Many consumers will take out their phones before their wallets this holiday season with even more visiting **social** media sites before tackling their gift lists[..]
Additionally, 44 percent say they plan to use **social** media to seek discounts, read reviews and check family and friendsâ€™ gift lists[..]
Many consumers will take out their phones before their wallets this holiday season with even more visiting social **media** sites before tackling their gift lists[..]
Additionally, 44 percent say they plan to use social **media** to seek discounts, read reviews and check family and friendsâ€™ gift lists[..]
```

Instead i want:

```
A new holiday shopping tradition: Smartphones and **social** networks[..]
Many consumers will take out their phones before their wallets this holiday season with even more visiting **social** **media** sites before tackling their gift lists[..]
Additionally, 44 percent say they plan to use **social** **media** to seek discounts, read reviews and check family and friendsâ€™ gift lists[..]
```

With fge code i get:

```
social[..] 
social[..] 
social[..] 
media[..] 
media[..]
```

I hope that with examples its easy to understand. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Your head will probably hurt less if you split the text into an array of sentences and examine each sentence in turn. If the list of words isn't too long you could put the entire list into your regex. Something like:

```
/\b(\Qword1\E|\Qword2\E|\Qword3\E)\b/
```

Comment: Sorry i dont know how to implemente this on my code, im regex null guy :D . I updated my question with examples.

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't get why you use such a complicated regex: you do use word anchors, so why bother with the complemented character classes?

Second, this solution assumes that words do not contains special regex characters...

Here is what you can do:

```
$w = preg_quote($word, "/");
$fullword = '\b\Q' . $w . '\E\b';
$regex = '/' . $fullword . '(?!.*' . $fullword . ')/i';
```

Explanation: `\Q` means that all characters, until `\E`, **should all be treated literally** (which means you are safe if the word contains a dot). So, you match your word (it is anchored), and then you say that you should NOT match the word again `(?!.*\b\Qwordhere\E\b)`.

This means that if a sentence contains the word several times, it will only match the last occurrence!

Finally, to highlight, use:

```
preg_replace('/(' . $fullword . ')/ig', '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>', $text);
```

Comment: I tried your code but im just getting the words, not the full sentence. I will update the question with an example